# How to substract year based on month in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

i have a query to retrieve data from current month and previous month..add_months(month,-1) used to get the previous month's data. But there is an year problem in the case of January.
If current month is January 2013, i need December 2012 as previous month. But its showing December 2013.
How can i correct it ?

see query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ot_day_coll_head, ot_day_coll_items,OM_SALESMAN
    WHERE olcd_olch_sys_id = olch_sys_id
       AND olch_sm_code=SM_CODE
       AND to_char(olch_doc_dt, 'Month')=TO_CHAR(ADD_Months(to_date('January','MM'),-1),'Month') 
       AND to_char(olch_doc_dt,'YYYY')='2013';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is forcing it to only look at 2013. You don't need to compare the year and month elements separately:

```
   AND to_char(olch_doc_dt, 'YYYY-MM')
       = TO_CHAR(ADD_Months(to_date('2013-01','YYYY-MM'),-1),'YYYY-MM')
```

Presumably you'll just substitute `sysdate` for the `to_date()` call since your question refers to the current month.

Quick [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13283).

Comment: Or `trunc(olch_doc_dt,'mm') = add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)`

Comment: ... and put an index on the to_char(olch_doc_dt, 'YYYY-MM') or trunc(olch_doc_dt,'mm')